ACC Docs Description Field
I'm using this endpoint to edit custom attributes associated with file metadata on ACC Docs.
"projects/{project_id}/versions/{version_id}/custom-attributes:batch-update"
[ link ]
Is there any endpoint that allow us to edit the standard "Description" field?

unfortunately, this has not been exposed. The wish ticket is: FDM-3886: Wish: Allow modification of [Description] field for Items. We appreciate for your patience.

Answered in the comments by @Xiaodong Liang : "unfortunately, this has not been exposed. The wish ticket is: FDM-3886: Wish: Allow modification of [Description] field for Items. We appreciate for your patience." Thanks for your input!
